# upgrading of datagrid from vb6 to vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb6, datagrid

I am upgrading from vb6 to vb.net.

I used to list my query results in datagrid in my previous applications. What can be more visually attractive control in replacement of datagrid?

Comment: Why ask the question twice? [DataList Control in vb.net windows application forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983462/datalist-control-in-vb-net-windows-application-forms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't remember what a DataGrid looks like. I assume the same control in VB.Net would be `DataGridView` and I'm fairly sure that you can probably make it look better than in VB6, but if you want really good looking ones you might want to look at thirdparty grid controls. There's quite a few, just google for `winforms grid control` and you should have plenty to choose from.

Comment: thnx working around with datagridview but its look up its little bit boring