# DataList Control in vb.net windows application forms

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, vb6, controls, datalist

I am upgrading my application from vb6 to vb.net.

I used to populate my data in datalist control in vb6 forms. I am not finding it in vb.net windows form application. Which one control is the equivalent to it?

How can i list my data in that control?

just like: 
I had a table with data like id, name

I want the name should be the displayed column and id the bound column? how can i do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure but I think you're looking for a `ListBox`. You create a class with 2 members and a property for each (suggested property names `ID` and `Name`), create a list of them and put all your data in there and then just set the 'ListBox.DisplayMember' to "Name" and `ListBox.ValueMember` to "ID".

The MSDN page for `ListControl.DisplayMember` has a full sample showing how to do it as can be seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx).

Though I'd suggest that you use a `List(Of YourClass)` rather than the `ArrayList` in the sample.

Comment: that was agr8 one... well can it be even done with combo box control instead of listbox

Comment: @KoolKabin: Sure, should work more or less exactly the same I think.